# VSCode Typescript with NextJS debugging

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I can't get any debug config to work with breakpoints and nextJS using typescript… Does anyone have one to share with me ?

Thanks

Comment: This actually works! Just a note, not to run the npm dev option. This will start and compile the server too.

Comment: I can confirm. [Top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442598/463304) works, but using `npm run dev` as [officially documented](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging) does not.

Comment: Same with @700Software, the official documentation was not working for me but the voted answer does!

Answer (score 4):

This is my `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next"
    }
  ]
}
```

Working for me with Next.js v9.4.4 in June 2020.

Comment: Works for me with Next 10 too.